# Vertical line at the end of a CDF histogram using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a CDF but at the end of the graph, there is a vertical line, shown below:

[image: plot]

I've read that his is because matplotlib uses the end of the bins to draw the vertical lines, which makes sense, so I added into my code as:

```
bins = sorted(X) + [np.inf]
```

where X is the data set I'm using and set the bin size to this when plotting:

```
plt.hist(X, bins = bins, cumulative = True, histtype = 'step', color = 'b')
```

This does remove the line at the end and produce the desired effect, however when I normalise this graph now it produces an error:

```
ymin = max(ymin*0.9, minimum) if not input_empty else minimum

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ymin' referenced before assignment
```

Is there anyway to either normalise the data with

```
bins = sorted(X) + [np.inf]
```

in my code or is there another way to remove the line on the graph?

Comment: Not sure why this got down-voted.  This is an artifact of how hist + step works.  You may be better off computing the cumulative histogram and then using `ax.step`.

Comment: Do you want a CDF or a histogram? If it's a CDF, which one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An alternative way to plot a CDF would be as follows (in my example, `X` is a bunch of samples drawn from the unit normal):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randn(10000)
n = np.arange(1,len(X)+1) / np.float(len(X))
Xs = np.sort(X)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.step(Xs,n)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a brilliant and beautiful alternative!

Comment: The problem that appears is that plot will be linearly interpolated inbetween dots, but the true cumulative function should have these "jumps".

Comment: Yes, that's probably a fair point - although it won't make much difference for large samples of data. Nonetheless, I have updated my answer to use `plt.step` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I needed a solution where I would not need to alter the rest of my code (using `plt.hist(...)` or, with pandas, `dataframe.plot.hist(...)`) and that I could reuse easily many times in the same jupyter notebook.

I now use this little helper function to do so:

```
def fix_hist_step_vertical_line_at_end(ax):
    axpolygons = [poly for poly in ax.get_children() if isinstance(poly, mpl.patches.Polygon)]
    for poly in axpolygons:
        poly.set_xy(poly.get_xy()[:-1])
```

Which can be used like this (without pandas):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.sort(np.random.randn(1000))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.hist(X, bins=100, cumulative=True, density=True, histtype='step')

fix_hist_step_vertical_line_at_end(ax)
```

Or like this (with pandas):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df.plot.hist(ax=ax, bins=100, cumulative=True, density=True, histtype='step', legend=False)

fix_hist_step_vertical_line_at_end(ax)
```

[image: result]

This works well even if you have multiple cumulative density histograms on the same axes.

**Warning:** this may not lead to the wanted results if your axes contain other patches falling under the `mpl.patches.Polygon` category. That was not my case so I prefer using this little helper function in my plots.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. I have a complementary CDF, so I just needed to change `poly.set_xy(poly.get_xy()[:-1])` to `poly.set_xy(poly.get_xy()[1:])`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your intentions are pure aesthetic, add a vertical line, of the same color as your plot background:

```
ax.axvline(x = value, color = 'white', linewidth = 2)
```

Where "value" stands for the right extreme of the rightmost bin.